# I'm not sure if I understand correctly how to call a new method in Java

Tags: java

I have the following exercise that I'm trying to solve:

> Write a class `Summing` with a method `public static void sumit()`. The
>   method computes the sum of all numbers between 1 an 200 which are
>   divisble by 7 and prints the result in the form
>
> "The sum is NUMBER"
>
> where "NUMBER" is the sum.

Here is what I've written so far:

```
public class Summing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        public static void sumit() {
            for(int i = 0; i <= 200; i += 7) {
                System.out.print("The sum is " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how I correctly call on the `sumit()` method here. Can anybody point out to me how I properly create the method `sumit()`?

Comment: Put your method *outside* of the `main`, and then just you can just call it like: `sumit()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The execution of a program always starts from the `main()` method, so you need to call the `sumit()` method inside the `main()` method, like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sumit();
}

public static void sumit() {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 200; i += 7) {
        System.out.print("The sum is " + i);
    }
}
```

But still there is issue with your code, which won't give you the sum of all numbers that are divisible by 7 between 0 and 200, so have a local variable which will add all numbers that are divisible by 7 in for loop

```
   public static void sumit() {
       int sum=0;
      for(int i = 0; i <= 200; i += 7) {
          sum+=i;  //sum = sum+i;
           System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
      }
   }
```

Comment: For an accepted answer, better point out that this method does not print out the sum of these numbers (and still needs to be worked on).

Comment: ya i can see that but maybe he will figure it out, and also SO is not place to write logic for him

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put a method inside another method so rather do this:

-Write your method outside the main method

```
public class Summing
{

   public static void main(String[] args)    
   {
      sumit();
   }

   public static void sumit() {
      for(int i = 0; i <= 200; i += 7) {
           System.out.print("The sum is " + i);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement correctly, this guy should do it.
Give it a try ;]

```
public class Summing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sumit();
    }

  public static void sumit() {
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
      if (i % 7 == 0) {
        sum = sum + i;    
      }
    }
    System.out.print("The sum is " + sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `new Summing()`?

Comment: Indeed, there is no need for that, thats a mistake.
Corrected